# How to customize/change the header logo of notification mail (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I have no idea where could I found the `header logo` example below(squared):

[image]


My content code:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage) 
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.'.$user->name)
        ->line('Hey Now hey now')
        ->action('Notification Action', route('register.select'))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

---

**EDITED:** in `email.blade.php`:

```
@component('mail::message')
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

... and so on, and so forth
```

---

I want to customize that `logo header`, my problem I can't find where exactly. Need your help Sirs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to customize mail templates.

Run this command:

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

After that you'll find templates in `resources/views/vendor/notifications`.

---

If you want to customize mail components used in templates:

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

You'll find components in `resources/views/vendor/mail`. The ones you want are `message.blade.php` and `header.blade.php`.

Comment: thanks Sir. I got the template which is `email.blade.php` but I can't find the part I want to customize.

Comment: I edited my post. can you help me Sir where the `logo header ` part

Comment: @escbooster12 Updated my answer.

Comment: that `header.blade.php` is the answer. Thanks Sir.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Updated the header for logo but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

It only shows the Laravel logo if the APP_NAME in the .env is set as "Laravel".

So once you change this setting it will omit the default logo. if you want to change it to display something else you can publish the mail components as other answers showed and customize it.

Comment: I already knew I had to do this, but needed to hear it from somebody else to be sure thanks!